# Запуск приложения внутри Intellig IDEA в отдельной консоли

Tags: intellij-idea, компиляция, terminal

Здравствуйте сообщество **StackOverflow**, я тут впервые и меня замучил один вопрос.

Когда я разрабатываю приложение на Java в IDEA IDE , приложение запускается изнутри IDE(Ну то-есть там свое окошко с выводом, все такое), так вот, есть ли возможность запускать приложения в **отдельной** консоли (оговорюсь, **linux**), так же как запускают консольные приложения например из VisualStudio (то есть нажал зеленый треугольник, и приложение запустилось в отдельном окошке, а не в IO внутри IDEA).

И если да то как это реализовать?

p.s. Я умею компилировать и запускать приложения которые написал внутри IDEA через консоль (javac все такое), я хочу это как то автоматизировать средствами самой IDEA (ну что бы не компилировать и не запускать все вручную).

Comment: зачем надо запускать его в отдельной консоли?

Comment: Например я пишу консольную игрушку. И в стандартном выводе idea отображение идет неправильное, и во время отладки самого приложения (тестовый запуск) нужно запустить его в консоли, потому что стандартный вывод реагирует медленнее